# Zipping textfiles in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to Archieve files for last three months in corresponding subfolders in a directory with no thrird party dlls.And they have to zip to the specific folder in their each subfolder with format name of the folder-yyyy/mm//dd.

Please help me to write code for this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.IO.Compression
Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx